# Bad Japanese formatting when rendering and generating in pdf

Tags: asp.net, api, pdf, web-deployment, font-family

I have created an API that generates a report in pdf format in japanese language. I have added the required font-families in the css. The report looks good when I run the api in local. although when I push it to pcf and then try to run it, some japanese characters are messed up.

**in local:** 
[image]

**from cloud:** 
[image]

I am stuck with this problem, need help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems more related to fonts, You may try:

1. Embedding the fonts in your application and on startup copy the fonts into the $HOME/.fonts directory (which for a running application is /home/vcap/app/.fonts). You can use .profile file to copy the file form your artefact to this location.
2. Use the font specifically in the code eg. from assets in java..something like

   GraphicsEnvironment graphenv = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
   graphenv.registerFont(Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new File("japanese.ttf")));